# PrestaShop Blocklayered issue with custom input

Tags: javascript, html, input, module, prestashop

I add to my product-list.tpl input with +/- buttons its works until I use any filter from blocklayered module, then +/- buttons stop working.

My input looks like:

```
<input type='button' value='-' class='qtymin' field='qty' />
<input type="text" class='qtynum' name="qty" id="quantity_to_cart_{$product.id_product|intval}" value="1"/>
<input type='button' value='+' class='qtypl' field='qty' />
```

Js code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // This button will increment the value
        $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
            // Stop acting like a button
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the field name
            fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
            // Get its current value
            var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
            // If is not undefined
            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                // Increment
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
            } else {
                // Otherwise put a 0 there
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
            }
        });
        // This button will decrement the value till 0
        $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
            // Stop acting like a button
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the field name
            fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
            // Get its current value
            var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
            // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                // Decrement one
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
            } else {
                // Otherwise put a 0 there
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
            }
        });
    });
```

Blocklayered v2.2.0 Prestashop v1.6.1.8

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried with $('parent_class').on.('click','qtyminus',function ....

Comment: Sorry but I not sure how to do that, I have basic knowledge about programming. Colud you give me a sample or write something more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to attach the event to the document:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // This button will increment the value
        $(document).on('click', '.qtyplus', function(e){
            // Stop acting like a button
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the field name
            fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
            // Get its current value
            var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
            // If is not undefined
            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                // Increment
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
            } else {
                // Otherwise put a 0 there
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
            }
        });
        // This button will decrement the value till 0
        $(document).on('click', '.qtyminus', function(e) {
            // Stop acting like a button
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the field name
            fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
            // Get its current value
            var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
            // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                // Decrement one
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
            } else {
                // Otherwise put a 0 there
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it was that simple :) I see it now but without your help I probably didn't solve it by my self.